# Is it possible to fetch tile sets with data conditions without the GL version of mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

I am currently using leaflet (target systems do not have GPU's).

I'm looking to retrieve tile sets from mapbox styles but need to add data conditions but there doesn't seem to be a way based from documentation.